# How to write a function to get one permuation of an array at a time in python

Tags: python, permutation

The code below gives all the permutations for the array, I want to write a function that can use one permutation at a time (I want to process one permutation at a time for example [2, 3, 5, 4, 1, 6] without generating them all in advance, to be able to use it in an objective function)

```
s = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
from itertools import permutations
for s_temp in permutations(s):
    print (s_temp)
```

Comment: `permutations(s)` is an iterator, so you can process "one permutation at a time" without generating them all in advance, isn't that what you want?

Comment: You're on the right track, but without a little more context, it isn't possible to tell you what to do.

Comment: Print consumes one permutation at a time? You could replace print with any function that acts on one permutation

Comment: just replace `print(s_temp)` with `my_objective_function(s_temp)` and you are set.

Answer (score 1):

You have several posibilities, starting that `permutations` returns a iterator so your code will just work by changing the `print` for whatever you need to call.

```
from itertools import permutations
def process(s):
    for s_temp in permutations(s):
        call_your_stuff(s_temp)
```

Also once you have the permutations object you can get the next item on it calling `next`:

```
from itertools import permutations
s = permutations(range(3))
s
<itertools.permutations object at 0x000000000377CFC0>
next(s)
(0, 1, 2)
```

If you want to process the same function for each of the permutations you can just use `map`, just replace the `lambda` function in the example for whatever you need to call:

```
s = permutations(range(3))
map(lambda (x, y, z): x+y-z, s)
[-1, 1, -1, 3, 1, 3]
```

You can collect the data into a list for further processing:

```
s = list(permutations(range(3))) 
s
[(0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 2, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 1, 0)]
```

Notice that if you dont collect the data (into a list, tuple, etc) once you consume the permutations object iterator that data will be "lost" (you will have to recalculate again)

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate it, this helps